# How to fill s3 production bucket? rails app + heroku + active records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, activerecord, dev-to-production

I am having a hard time getting s3 images to show in deployment. I have 2 buckets on aws s3, one for dev and for production.

[image: this is the development bucket]

only the production bucket get filled up with images when I run the code below for my images. (You can see this on the images I attached) I also dont get any errors on chrome console.

```
Restaurant.last.main_photo.attach(io: File.open("/home/vault/Desktop/halal-table-photos/profile-photos/blur-breakfast-chef-cooking-262978.jpg"), filename: "23.jpg")
```

I've tried the Open-uri gem

```
require 'open-uri'


Restaurant.last.main_photo.attach(io: open("/home/vault/Desktop/halal-table-photos/profile-photos/blur-breakfast-chef-cooking-262978.jpg"), filename: "23.jpg")
```

[image: this the production bucket]

Here are my s3 setups

[image: creds]
[image: storage-yml]
[image: sdk-gem]

https://github.com/MahmudAhmed/HalalTable <- git repo
 
https://halal-table.herokuapp.com/#/restaurants 
 
https://halal-table.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I examine your project from Github. There is no visible problem on the code, but only thing I didn't see here is your Heroku config. You need to either say Heroku to use specific bucket for production via heroku config vars or initialize `config/initializers/aws.rb` and say heroku to use different bucket in production. [In here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails) you can get really got information about s3 buckets in Rails with different environments in action.

Comment: I just set the bucket variable on heroku to my production bucket and ran the code to attach the photos but the production one doesnt get filled. Is there a specific code I should run?